# quantmod <- Having trouble writing a formula to extract single day returns without headers

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, financial, quantitative-finance

I am attempting to write a formula that will return a stocks single day return, but I believe im having trouble with the data type of the `periodReturn` `subset` field

```
periodReturn(ticker,period='daily',subset='20161010::20161010')
```

works but

```
dayReturn <- function(ticker,date) {

ticker <- c(MSFT)
date <- c(20161010)
dayreturn <- periodReturn(ticker,period='daily',paste("subset='",date,"::",date,"'"))
dayreturn
}
```

gives error

`dayReturn(msft,20161010)`

```
 daily.returns
Warning messages:
1: In as_numeric(YYYY) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as_numeric(MM) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In as_numeric(DD) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors going on here inside your `dayReturn` function.

Here is reproducible code extracted from inside your function that will work:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("MSFT")

ticker <- c(MSFT)
date <- c("20161010")
dayreturn <- periodReturn(ticker,period='daily',subset = paste0(date,"::",date,"'"))
```

Your errors:

1. `date` wants to be a string, not a numeric number.
2. Your string for the dates you want to subset over is incorrect.  you want to use `subset = "YYYYMMDD::YYYYMMDD"` or (`subset = "YYYY-MM-DD::YYYY-MM-DD"`) in side `periodReturn`.

Your function would work more correctly like this:

```
dayReturn <- function(ticker, date1 , date2) {
    dayreturn <- periodReturn(ticker,period='daily',subset = paste0(date1,"::",date2,"'"))
    dayreturn
}

dayReturn(MSFT, "20161010", "20161012")
# daily.returns
# 2016-10-10   0.004152284
# 2016-10-11  -0.014645107
# 2016-10-12  -0.001398811
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue. Really appreciate the time and assistance -

Comment: @FrankDrin No worries.  if you feel this answers your question (along with all the other questions you've asked SO), you might like to consider accepting the answer, and other people's answers to your other questions (the green tick).

Comment: As you can see FXQuantTrader... still new to this :) Done, thanks for the heads up !